# Silverstripe Blog - Recent posts from a specific blog on homepage

Tags: php, blogs, silverstripe

I am trying to include recent blogposts from a specific blog in my Silverstripe homepage. I have this code returning posts from ALL my blog pages (there are two on the site):

```
public function latestBlog($num = 3) {
    return BlogPost::get()
        ->sort('PublishDate', 'desc')
        ->limit($num);
}
```

. Advice on how to specify the blog ID in a filter?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to filter by the correct blog to start with, then apply your sort and limit to the blog posts that belong to it, for example:

```
public function latestBlog($num = 3)
{
    return Blog::get()                               // <- DataList of Blogs
        ->filter('URLSegment', 'your-specific-blog') // <- target a specific Blog
        ->first()                                    // <- get that specific Blog
        ->Children()                                 // <- get the BlogPost children for it
        ->sort('PublishDate', 'desc')                // <- sort the BlogPosts
        ->limit($num);                               // <- limit the list
}
```

Note that this doesn't include any error checking - e.g. the `->first()` call could return null so it'd be worth checking that before continuing.

You could also move the URLSegment filter into a function argument, or swap it for any other property filter.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance, and I apologise for the delay in responding. I have edited my code, however am having no success - the function is not returning a result, despite having the correct URLSegment listed in the filter.